# Entity Framework throws unexpected exceptions with a heavy workload

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, wcf, iis

We have a operating project with MSSQL2016, EntityFramework and WCF Services on IIS. In the normal situations all things are good but when workload increased, the EntityFramework throws unusual exceptions on linq queries:

> ... ToList -> .ctor -> MoveNext -> TryReadToNextElement -> MoveNext ->
>   MaterializeRow -> HasNextElement -> lambda_method-> IsDBNull ->
>   CheckHeaderIsReady
>
> **System.IndexOutOfRangeException**: Index was outside the bounds of the
>   array.

-

> ... FirstOrDefault -> MoveNext -> TryReadToNextElement -> MoveNext ->
>   MaterializeRow -> HasNextElement -> lambda_method -> GetGuid ->
>   get_SqlGuid
>
> **System.InvalidCastException**: Specified cast is not valid.

-

> ... FirstOrDefault -> MoveNext -> ReadNextElement -> lambda_method ->
>   GetValue
>
> **System.InvalidOperationException**: The specified cast from a
>   materialized 'System.Int32' type to the 'System.Guid' type is not
>   valid.

****NOTE: columns of database tables and properties of data model have same type. and this error is not about casting.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [{"The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Guid' type to the 'System.Int32' type is not valid."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38377943/the-specified-cast-from-a-materialized-system-guid-type-to-the-system-int32)

Comment: Are you sharing db context instance between multiple threads?

Comment: @IvanStoev no, I create db context per service call. when workload increased, all users takes these exceptions. I think about concurrency on db context but I can't find anything.I don't know the main reason of these errors

Comment: It really looks like you are sharing some state, which cannot be shared, between multiple threads. I'd ensure once again that it's not the case. Hard to say anything more with provided information

Comment: How are you scoping the DbContext to the request? Through an IoC container? To test for concurrency issues across a DbContext instance, output trace with the method and the DbContext.GetHashCode() value. Aside from that you may need to post up additional code about how your DbContext is being used on these calls that are failing, what is being returned, and callstack information or the line(s) these operations are crashing on. For API-like calls under load ideally you should consider async operations /w await to free up worker threads to process load efficiently.

Comment: @StevePy I don't use IoC container. i just create dbcontext in ctor of service class and my wcf config are PerCall type.

Comment: I know it doesn't necessarily help, but we've been experiencing the exact same problem except that we're only using ASP.NET MVC (no WCF involved) on IIS. We see the same sort of exceptions for many (all?) current requests for a short interval on individual servers. Presumably when the server is under considerable load, though I'm not 100% sure about that. I've been tackling this problem for months and have unfortunately made no progress towards finding a solution.

Comment: @JosephDaigle did you find a solution for this problem? I'm experiencing the same on ASP.NET Core + EF 6.4 under heavy load.

Comment: @ArMaN Can't reference 2 users on same comment.

Comment: @CiubotariuFlorin no. The errors occur with less frequency than in the past. But I think that may be due to less load on the database server.

Answer (score 0):

Could the issue be the way you handle the work load? Because you are trying to access an index which does not exist or which is not yet in existence(delayed) in the list. I found some article here [WCF - IndexOutOfRange exception when instantiating ChannelFactory](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2bab45c1-6ba1-4998-96e7-be7b9888f4ae/wcf-indexoutofrange-exception-when-instantiating-channelfactory?forum=wcf)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's related to this bug, https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/659. I think it's been back-ported to .NET Framework: https://support.microsoft.com/help/5020622